# Spring Framework , feature toggle and Multi war project

Tags: spring, toggle

Does spring have a mechanism which allows multi war projects communicate with each other?

I want to create a solution whereby the features in my application are controlled by a central point (possibly a html page in one of the WAR files) and when an update is made to turn on/off the feature this change is propagated down to the correct WAR which may use annotations or possibly spring profiles to act on the communicated change.

I've looked at a couple of frameworks like Togglz and Fitchy which provide a feature toggle solution however neither is ideal for my requirements.

All suggestions welcome.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring have an integration with JMS that can be used in such situation. [Check it out](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/jms.html). All available options are listed [here](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/remoting.html#remoting-introduction) (including RMI, Spring's HTTP invoker, Hessian, Burlap, JAX-RPC and JAX-WS). Advantage of asyncronous approach like JMS is that it is better from fault tolerance point of view (you can more easily handle the situation where app1 sends a message to app2 which is temporarily turned off). On the other hand if fault tolerance does not metter then some syncronous solution like JAX-WS may be more easy to do. Hope it helps.